# How to add comma every 3 digits without using number format?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to format a value,

Example:

```
1526374856.03
```

to:

```
1,526,374,856.03
```

Comment: What do you have against NumberFormat?

Comment: The problem that the user can change the phone language and this app is only for Mexico

Comment: You can specify the locale.

Comment: ok, but how can I achieve that? I would apreciate it a lot

Comment: Achieve what? Did you look up the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)?

Comment: NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US); nf.format(number);

Comment: that worked for me. thanks

Comment: @LuisAguilar you can answer your own question for future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it **without using `NumberFormat`**, you can convert the number to a String and do the following code:

```
double number = 1526374856.03;
String[] array = Double.toString(number).split(".");
String numString = array[0];

String newString = "";
for(int i = 0; i < numString.length() ; i++){
    if((numString.length() - i - 1) % 3 == 0){
        newString += Character.toString(numString.charAt(i)) + ",";
    }else{
        newString += Character.toString(numString.charAt(i));
    }
}
newString += array[1];
```

`newString` is now the new String that contains the number with the commas.

Comment: `split(".")` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: This code will give a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll look into why this error is occurring.

Comment: `Double.toString(number)` doesn't even do what you think

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it adds the "E" to the end. Would you happen to know a method that converts a double to a String without adding the "E"?

Comment: http://www.java67.com/2014/06/how-to-format-float-or-double-number-java-example.html

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way to set the amount formats in android. Initialize `NumberFormat` variable as shown below and the just call the `Numberformat` variable name and the method `format`.

In This case my boolean number is `any_number` variable and I specify Locale.US because of the country.

```
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);

    nf.format(any_number);
```

Hope this helps some one.

Comment: Adding some explanation would make this answer more useful.

Comment: Hope this helps @SagarZala

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/**
 * data format
 *
 * @param data
 * @return
 */
public static String bigDecimalData(String data) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble(data));
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(",###,####.00");
        return df.format(bd);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this

```
    private String formatNumber(String number) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(number);
        String string = String.valueOf(number);

        if(string.contains("."))
            string= (String) string.subSequence(0,string.indexOf("."));

        if(string.length() > 3) {
            int firstComma=(string.length() % 3);
            int countComma = (string.length()-1)/3;

            if(firstComma != 0)
                stringBuilder.insert(firstComma, ",");

            for(int i = stringBuilder.indexOf(",")+4; i<string.length()+countComma; i+=4)
                stringBuilder.insert(i, ",");
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```